# Single Sign on Windows Authentication popup

Tags: authentication-authorization

I enabled SSO on my drupal website. 
When a user surfs to my website they got a windows authentication popup to fill in their AD credentials (i work with LDAP).

But how do I pass the credentials automaticly without the popup?